# How can I pass a list of unknown length to a haskell function?

Tags: list, function, haskell, list-comprehension

```
secondTest :: [(Int, Int)] -> [Int] -> [Int]
secondTest a b = [ x | (m,n) <- a, x <- b,  m > 3 && n > 3]
```

I have this code at the moment and I want to change it so that it will return b if all of the int given are more than 3, no matter how many ints are given in the first list.

I have tried something like this:

```
secondTest :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
secondTest a b = [ x | m <- a, x <- b,  m > 3]
```

but this returns a value if *any* of the int values are more than 3, rather than all of them.

edit to show expected return:

```
secondTest [4,4] [1,2] = [1,2]
secondTest [4,4,4] [1,2] = [1,2]
secondTest [4,1,4] [1,2,9] = Nothing
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you need to return when not all values are > 3 ? Perhaps you should provide some examples showing the expected result. E.g. `f [4,4] [1,2] = ?`, `f [4,4,4] [1,2] = ?`, `f [4,1,4] [1,2,9] = ?`, etc.

Comment: @chi Hey! I've edited it to include this, hope this helps you

Answer (score 2):

You can test if all the elements of `a` are larger than 3 using `all`:

```
secondTest :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
secondTest a b
   | all (> 3) a = b 
   | otherwise   = ...
```

Note that in the `otherwise` case we still have to return a list, so we can't return `Nothing`. We can return an empty list

```
secondTest a b
   | all (> 3) a = b 
   | otherwise   = []
```

or we can change the return type of the function

```
secondTest :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
secondTest a b
   | all (> 3) a = Just b 
   | otherwise   = Nothing
```

You can't directly do this with a list comprehension. At best, you could use one to generate the list of elements that are `<= 3`, and then test whether that is empty, reversing the logic:

```
secondTest a b
   | null [ x | x <- a, x <= 3 ] = Nothing
   | otherwise                   = Just b
```

Comment: Thanks! How would this change if list a was a list of boolean functions being applied to a single int instead? ie. first item is a function that returns true if the int is >3, and the second item is a function that returns true if the int is even. Then, if all these functions returned true, it would return b. For example, something like this: ```thirdTest :: [listOfFunctions] -> [Int] -> [Int]
thirdTest a b
   | all (listOfFunctions) b = b 
   | otherwise   = []``` It would apply the functions in listOfFunctions to each item in the Int list, and then return those that satisfy all functions?